# How do I handle multiple play2 WS calls for a Set of objects and then return the successful calls to view

Tags: web-services, scala, asynchronous, playframework, playframework-2.1

Let say that in my Controller I have a set of **Sms** objects. For each one of those objects I would like to call a web service and then for all the successful calls return the sms objects to view.

**Controller:**

```
def inviteBySms() = Action {
    implicit request => {
      val smsSet = getSet()
      Async {
        smsSet.map(sms => callSmsService(sms).map(response => {
          response.status match {
            case 200 => {
              // somehow add the sms object to a success set  
            }
            case _ => {
              // ignore
            }
          }
        }))
      // Return Ok() with the success Set[SMS]
      }
    } 

}
```

**method in Controller:**

```
def postToService(sms: Sms) = {

    val params = Map(Seq(current.configuration.getString("sms.service.user").getOrElse("")),
          "pass" -> Seq(current.configuration.getString("sms.service.password").getOrElse("")),
          "mobilephone" -> Seq(sms.number))
        )


    val futureResponse = WS.url(Play.current.configuration
          .getString("sms.service.url").getOrElse(""))
          .withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8")
          .post(params)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further discussion, here is a most correct answer than my first attempt.

In my code I've just defined Sms as `type Sms = String` and I'm just calling directly WS.url().get on it.

First, the `callSmsService(sms: Sms)` should call the service and not return the `Response` but already `map()` it depending on whether the return is 200 or not. The idea is to return back the original `Sms` instance or `None` so that we can aggregate them later :

```
def callSmsService(sms: Sms): Future[Option[Sms]] = {
  WS.url(sms).get
    .map { 
      response => if (response.status == 200) Some(sms) else None
    }
}
```

You can now `map()` your initial Sms set with this function:

`val futureOptionSet: Set[Future[Option[Sms]]] = smsSet.map { sms => callSmsService(sms) }`

Then, you have to transform the `Set[Future]` into a global `Future[Set]` (you need a unique Future to construct a `Future[Result]` asked by `Async{...}`):

`val optionSetFuture: Future[Set[Option[Sms]]] = Future.sequence(futureOptionSet)`

Now, you can map the global Future to collect only successfull Sms

`val smsSetFuture: Future[Set[Sms]] = optionSetFuture.map { set => set.collect { case Some(sms) => sms }}`

With this last `Future`, you can now do a `map()` to build a `Future[Response]`

```
smsSetFuture.map( successfulSmsSet: Set[Sms] => {
  // do something with successfulSmsSet
  ok(...) 
})
```

I have detailed step by step with explicit return types but you can of course combine several steps without the intermediate values and explicit types.

Comment: Great walkthrough! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

First, I would call :

```
smsSet.map(sms => callSmsService(sms))
```

to get a Set[Future[Response]] and wrap it with Future.sequence to get a Future[Set[Response]] :

```
Future.sequence(smsSet.map(sms => callSmsService(sms)))
```

And then on the Future[Set[Response]] you can filter() and map() to get a Future[Set[SMS]]

```
val futureSetSms = Future.sequence(smsSet.map(sms => callSmsService(sms)))
   .filter{_.status == 200}
   .map(response => {...construct your SMS...})
```

You then just have to map that to a Future[Result] that can be used by Async{} :

```
futureSetSms.map { smsSet => Ok(...) }
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer! I'm not sure I follow you all the way =) On .filter{_.status == 200} I get a expected: (Set[Response]) => Boolean actual: (Set[Response]) => Any. Also the response is mapped to ...construct your SMS... I'm not sure I understand this.. Sorry for being such a noob. Could you elaborate further?

Comment: In fact I didn't understood that you wanted to retrieve to SMS object initially used (I thought you where constructed a new object from the WS reponse). I'll try to update my answer with that in mind.

Comment: Aha ok! I understand! Yes the initial object if the response is 200. Thank you!